# qemu error while running my boot

Tags: arm, boot, qemu, bootloader

I wrote a short boot code and tried to run it with Qemu with:

> qemu-system-arm.exe -M versatilepb -cpu cortex-a9 -kernel boot.bin

I expected the code to be loaded to address 0x8400000 but qemu returned me the error

> Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0x84000000
>   This usually means one of the following happened:
>
> (1) You told QEMU to execute a kernel for the wrong machine type, and it crashed on startup (eg trying to run a raspberry pi kernel on a versatilepb QEMU machine)
>   (2) You didn't give QEMU a kernel or BIOS filename at all, and QEMU executed a ROM full of no-op instructions until it fell off the end
>   (3) Your guest kernel has a bug and crashed by jumping off into nowhere
>
> This is almost always one of the first two, so check your command line and that you are using the right type of kernel for this machine.
>   If you think option (3) is likely then you can try debugging your guest with the -d debug options; in particular -d guest_errors will cause the log to include a dump of the guest register state at this point.
>
> Execution cannot continue; stopping here.

So I guess my code has not yet started running because it is not loaded into the right place

What am I wrong about?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You say "I expected the code to be loaded to address 0x8400000" but QEMU's error message says "0x84000000" which is not the same number (it has an extra 0). This suggests that you have a typo in your linker script or whatever is creating your boot.bin file. (I am assuming that boot.bin is an ELF file, which QEMU loads at the addresses the ELF file specifies, because otherwise it will be loaded into RAM anyhow on the assumption that it's a Linux kernel image capable of self-relocation.)

Comment: About the extra 0 - My mistake, i mean 0x84000000.

Comment: If 0x84000000 is where you expect the ELF file to be loaded, then QEMU's behaviour is correct -- there is no RAM at that address. You need to build your binary so that it loads where the board has RAM, not into nothingness.